# Android how to show hidden item only for one row on click

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclick

im trying to create a listView, that has an Button item on it.
I want to make this button clickable, so I did something like this code in Adapter, getView:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("_myButton_Log", "ShowOnClick");
            }
        });
```

And now im trying to change the visibility parameter for my textView:

```
TextView myDesc = row.findViewById(R.id.my_desc);
myDesc.setVisibility(convertView.GONE);
```

I want to show this textView in only one row, after click this button.

Now I make that, the button is clickable for each rows but as you can see it's show only the Log. Im a newbie in the ListViews and buttons on it and im trying to get knowledge how to make it work, but for now I cannot find any help...

So im begging here for some help! :)

Anyway if you want me to use the OnItemClickListener it's not possible because im using it for another way.

Comment: I am not gettnig the point clearly. You have list and every item has a clickable button. Now please make it clear that by tapping on button how your code should behave? and how its now behaving? Try to edit your answer to make things more clear

Comment: Hi! 
i mean that, every row in the listview have the button, and some items with visibility set to gone, now i want to click this batton in example row and set the visibility of those items to visible after clicking on this button but only for this one row :)

Comment: that's clear for you?

Comment: Alright i understood. Is it possible to share your code via git? So i can resolve it for you.

Comment: Hi, it is possible but you probably cannot get the list, because list view is building from json from rest request response. Can I beg you for making example list view with this button? I appreciate you!

Comment: Are you using recycler veiw or listview?

Comment: Hi, im using ListView :)

Comment: Sorry for late response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out an response for my question.

Everyone with this problem - just need to make a simple action for a button in list view in your adapter like:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        TextView myPrice = row.findViewById(R.id.price);
        Button myButton = row.findViewById(R.id.button);

        myPrice.setVisibility(convertView.VISIBLE);
        myButton.setVisibility(convertView.GONE);
    }
});
```